Build Failure: Missing 'icon.png' in LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinUI during WinUI Project Packaging
I'm working on a small hobby project. I was trying to package a WinUI application witch uses LiveCharts. However I'm getting an error when packaging the application.
Anyone who has experienced something similar?
I have posted the same question to LiveChars, but I'm not expecting a answer soon. Therefor i decided to ask here as well.
Description
During the build process for packaging a WinUI project in Visual Studio, an error occurs stating that icon.png is not found. The error indicates that this file is expected to be in the LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinUI images directory but it is not present, resulting in a build failure with the following error message: ...LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinUI\images\icon.png does not exist.
Screenshot:
Screenshot of Error Message
Desktop:
OS: Windows
Version: Windows 10 SDK version 19041 targeted with .NET 7.0 (net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0). Minimum supported Windows version is set to 17763.
Package Version:
LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinUI Version: 2.0.0-rc2.1
Thanks in advance.
To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Open the project solution in Visual Studio.
Right-click on the packaging project within the Solution Explorer.
Choose 'Rebuild' from the context menu.
Observe the error in the Output window which indicates that the file icon.png is missing.

Expected behavior
The expected outcome is for the build process to succeed without encountering missing file errors, especially when no such resource is explicitly required by the application.
